# How to use key and value in RS Tag for API testing

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

Where do we mention the body parameters like key and value in RS Tag for API testing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a param tag under rs  using param tag you can pass the parameter name and values.

param is a sub-tag used with “rs” tag if the webservice request requires parameters to be passed. Attributes “name” and “value” are used to store the name and value of the parameters.